# Crash from -extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: sqliteopenhelper

I have a multi-Activity App which utilizes an SQLite DB and is working as designed.  However, I am adding a feature and it now has trouble Writing Back to the DB

To keep it simple I will focus on 2 of the Activities/Classes (Activity1, and Activity2) and the DBHelper class AND I will use Pseudo Code.

The classes are defined :

```
public class Activity 1  extends Activity implements OnClickListener  
public class Activity 2  extends Activity implements OnClickListener  
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Activity 1 Uses DBHelper to READ data from a DB on TWO separate occasions from TWO different tables without any problems.  It then CLOSES the DB.

A1 Reads and displays some of the data, (and does some other stuff) then passes Data that was read from DB to Activity 2.

A2 performs some magic on the data, as I said.. there are NO problems.

Things go south when I try to open the DB from Activity 2.

I wrote a new method INSIDE the DBHelper class to:

1. Open the DB
2. WRITE data
3. Close the DB

We will call that DBwriter () to keep it simple, but it CRASHES (NullPointerException) when I call DBwriter () FROM A2.

However, when I step thru with the debugger I can see that it NEVER gets to the method DBwriter ().  On the line that calls DBwriter () it blows up and left a mess on the floor.

After scratching my head for a while (and sweeping up all of the 1s and 0s off the floor),  I edited A1 and made a call to DBwriter ()

And it DID NOT CRASH. It stepped right thru the method. So, there was NO PROBLEM with DBwriter ().

I edited DBwriter () -- remember it is Located INSIDE the DBHelper class--
and removed EVERYTHING but the bare bones.  Like this:

```
public void DBwriter ()  
{ int Debug = 1; //  this is so I can place a Break Point  
}
```

Yet, in A2, it still crashes when CALLING DBwriter () and NEVER even gets to the first line of the code!!

I am suspecting that it has something to do with extends SQLiteOpenHelper

In A1, there is a variable: private DBHelper m_myDbHelper

Now... when I create a second instance of a variable in a SEPARATE class in a Second Activity, A2... does that cause something to Blow Up because I am using DBHelper Two Times??  I could create a new class for writing, but I think it Should Work from ONE DBHelper Class.

I am NOT doing anything WEIRD in the Constructor or onCreate

Here is the Constructor:

```
public DBHelper (Context context) {
  super (context, DB_NAME, null, 1);  
  this.myContext = context;  
}
```

Here is onCreate:

```
@Override  
public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db) {    
}
```

Comment: Can I add the Android Tag AFTER it has been submitted??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Crashes in SQLiteOpenHelper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127450/android-crashes-in-sqliteopenhelper)